# What x86 register denotes source location in movsb instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

What x86 register denotes source location in movsb instruction?

Comment: That is the entry question of `osdev.org`!

Comment: exactly!. may be even i had googled when i wanted to join osdev

Comment: @ManuHegde Hey, at least it's unlikely that you're a bot, then. Which was what the question was supposed to guard against. ;-)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In 32-bit mode, `esi`.

In specific, `movsb` copies one byte from `ds:esi` to `es:edi`, then increments or decrements both `esi` and `edi` by 1, depending on the direction flag (DF).

Intel's manuals have a detailed reference entry for every instruction.
An HTML scrapes of the PDF has [and entry for `movs`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq), and for [`rep movs`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz).

Comment: A bit of related x86 trivia for today's youth - `SI` (or `ESI` in the 32-bit world) stands for 'source index' and `DI` stands for 'destination index', which comes from the special-purpose uses of these registers.

Comment: Also be aware the default segment registers DS and ES can be overridden to use other segment registers.

Comment: @I. J. Kennedy: Only the `ds` can be overridden. The `es` is fixed.

Comment: In general, any instruction that uses `ds` by default can be overridden with a segment prefix; any instruction that uses `es` (e.g., `stosb` and the like) is fixed and cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 10):

**How to extract that information from the manual**

Now that you've logged into osdev.org, it's time to pay your moral debt by actually learning it. :-)

[Intel Manual Volume 2 Instruction Set Reference - 325383-056US September 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025081307/http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) section "MOVS/MOVSB/MOVSW/MOVSD/MOVSQ—Move Data from String to String" says:

> Moves the byte, word, or doubleword specified with the second operand (source operand) to the location specified
>   with the first operand (destination operand). Both the source and destination operands are located in memory. The
>   address of the source operand is read from the DS:ESI or the DS:SI registers

**Minimal test program**

Finally, you must make a minimal program that uses the instruction to see if you've understood it correctly:

```
section .data
    src db 0
    dest db 1
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov esi, src
    mov edi, dest
    cld
    movsb
    /* dest == 0*/
```

Runnable version of this with assertions [on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/assembly-cheat/blob/ba3b76cd4530268d4c34e29c354d399c0d8552fc/ia-32/movs.asm).